# Problema iconos vscode

Tags: vscode

Como están? tengo una duda.

Estoy usando ***material icon theme*** en vscode, el problema esta en que tengo 2 proyectos, uno de angular y otro de nestjs

cuando uso el de angular (con redux), para poder visualiar los iconos correctamente, debo poner el packicon de angular + redux

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esto consigo que se vean los iconos que necesito, tanto de angular como de redux (lo que hace esto es agregar la siguiente linea a "settings.json" )

```
"material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "angular_ngrx",
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora el problema que esto queda activado y cuando me paso al proyecto de nest (o viceversa) tengo que volver a cambiar la configuracion del pack para que se vean los iconos acorde..

NESTJS:
Activo la configuracion del pack para nestjs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pasa a verse asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Es un poco tedioso tener que andar cambiando la configuracion cada vez que entro a un proyecto distinto.

Probe hacer una configuracion de workspace, **pero la linea que hace el cambio de iconos no funciona.**

**settings.json (global,user)**

```js
{

    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Source Code Pro for Powerline",
    "editor.wordWrap":"on",
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
}
```

**settings.json (del proyecto)**

```js
{
    "material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "angular_ngrx",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
}
```

La linea que deberia cambiarme los iconos:

```
"material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "angular_ngrx",
```

no funciona,mientras que la del fontsize funciona perfectamente.

Ahora si esa misma linea la paso al settings.json, si funciona. Pero vuelvo al principio, por cada proyecto tengo que cambiarlo manual cada vez que entro

Comment: ¿Tu problema realmente es que quieres diferenciar por la UI del editor cuando estas en uno u otro proyecto? Hay extensiones para eso, como https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock

Comment: Igual, esta pregunta es mas para quien hizo la extension. que para este lugar.. probaste hacerla ahi?